# Retrieve Authentication Object using session id in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Using SessionRegistry object, I have retrieved SessionInformation for all the active sessions of a user.

Now, I want now to check authorities of these sessions. To do that I need Authentication Object.

Is there way to this in spring securtity

My Code:

```
List<SessionInformation> sessionInformationList =  sessionRegistry.getAllSessions( user, false);
SessionInformation sessionInformation = sessionRegistry.getSessionInformation(lastSessionId);

//Now I need Authentication Object, any idea
```

I am doing this so as to retrieve user roles for different session ids

Comment: Get the principal from SessionInformation. Then, you should have a UserDetailsService somewhere in your context. Get that and then call loadUserByUsername(String username).

Comment: @ArunM Didn't used UserDetailsService, used custom implementation of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

Answer (score 1):

In our [Stormpath Spring Security integration](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-spring-security) we coded what you need during the authentication workflow. Once the user has been properly authenticated, the `Granted Authorites` are generated and applied to the `Authentication` object being retrieved.

We encapsulate that information in an object called `StormpathUserDetails`. You can take a look at [this piece of code](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/stormpath/spring/security/provider/StormpathAuthenticationProvider.java#L369).

Your code then can retrieve that information this way: `Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = ((StormpathUserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getAuthorities();`

Hope this helps as an example for what you could do.

Comment: To clarify, your above implementation will give authorities of present session of user, not all the sessions of user. I want to find out authorities in any session of user using session Id.